# Does projection of a simplicial subdivision of a simplex onto a lower-dimensional face generate a subdivision of that face?

Tags: combinatorics, general-topology, geometry, algebraic-topology, convex-analysis

My goal is to prove that any simplicial subdivision (or triangulation) of a simplex generates a simplicial subdivision on the faces of the original simplex.

Formally, let $n,k$ be integers such that $n\geq\max\{k,1\}$ and $k\geq0$. Suppose that the vectors $x^1,\ldots,x^{k+1}\in\mathbb R^n$ are affinely independent, that is, for any $\alpha_1,\ldots,\alpha_{k+1}\in\mathbb R$, one has $$\sum_{i=1}^{k+1}\alpha_ix^i=\underbrace{(0,\ldots,0)}_{\text{$n$-vector}}\,\,\text{ and }\,\,\sum_{i=1}^{k+1}\alpha_i=0\quad\text{if and only if}\quad\alpha_1=\cdots=\alpha_{k+1}=0,$$ and let $$\bigtriangleup(x^1,\ldots,x^{k+1})\equiv\left\{\sum_{i=1}^{k+1}\lambda_ix^i\,\Bigg|\,\lambda_1,\ldots\lambda_{k+1}\geq0\text{ and }\sum_{i=1}^{k+1}\lambda_i=1\right\}$$ be the $k$-simplex generated by them.

Consider a simplicial subdivision $\mathscr T$, where

- $\mathscr T$ is a non-empty finite set consisting of $k$-simplices;
- $\bigcup_{T\in\mathscr T}T=\bigtriangleup(x^1,\ldots,x^{k+1})$; and
- if $T,T'\in\mathscr T$ and $T\cap T'\neq\varnothing$, then $T\cap T'$ is a face of both $T$ and $T'$; that is, $T\cap T'$ is a simplex all of whose vertices are also vertices of both $T$ and $T'$.

Now consider “projecting” the elements of $\mathscr T$ onto a face of the original simplex. Formally, consider the face $\bigtriangleup(x^1,\ldots,x^{k})$ of $\bigtriangleup(x^1,\ldots,x^k,x^{k+1})$, and define $$\mathscr E\equiv\bigcup_{T\in\mathscr T}\left\{E\,|\,\text{$E$ is a face of $T$ with $k$ vertices and }E\subseteq\bigtriangleup(x^1,\ldots,x^{k})\right\}.$$

> I wish to show that $\mathscr E$ is a simplicial subdivision of the face $\bigtriangleup(x^1,\ldots,x^{k})$.
>
> (In particular, that $\mathscr E\neq\varnothing$).

The idea is intuitively obvious geometrically: take the vertices of members of $\mathscr T$ that lie in the face $\bigtriangleup(x^1,\ldots,x^{k})$, then omit the vertex from each such $T\in\mathscr T$ that is not on this face. Yet, I’m struggling with formalizing this algebraically. Any suggestion would be greatly appreciated.

---

While the geometric intuition is pretty obvious, I’m struggling with coming up with a rigorous algebraic formalization. The key issue is that while every element in the face $\bigtriangleup(x^1,\ldots,x^k)$ is clearly contained in some $T\in\mathscr T$, it is all too well possible that this $T$ merely *touches* $\bigtriangleup(x^1,\ldots,x^k)$ at one point/segment/low-dimensional face, as opposed to having a $k-1$-dimensional face that is *fully* included in $\bigtriangleup(x^1,\ldots,x^k)$!

Comment: (i) I think the choice of the $x_i$ is irrelevant, and you may as well take the standard simplex in $\Bbb R^{k+1}$. (ii) it's usual to regard the faces of simplices in the triangulation as elements of the triangulation, and if you do this  then the simplices in the triangulation contained in say $\Delta(x_1,\ldots,x_n)$ form a triangulation of $\Delta(x_1,\ldots,x_n)$.

Comment: @LordSharktheUnknown How do I know that there _are_ faces of the subsimplices in the triangulation contained in the face $\bigtriangleup(x^1,\ldots,x^k)$? While the geometric intuition is obvious, I’m struggling with coming up with a rigorous algebraic formalization. The key issue is that while every element in the face $\bigtriangleup(x^1,\ldots,x^k)$ is clearly contained in some $T\in\mathscr T$, it is possible that this $T$ merely _touches_ $\bigtriangleup(x^1,\ldots,x^k)$, as opposed to being _fully_ included in it!

Comment: How can "$E$ be a subset of $T$ with $k$ vertices" and not equal $\Delta(x^1, \dots, x^k)$?

Comment: I'm going to open my Munkres' book and see if I can follow along with you.  This is exciting!

Comment: @EnjoysMath It is weaker than linear independence—I added the definition. As for your other comment: for example, let $n=k=2$, so that $k+1=3$. If you cut a triangle in the plane into, say, four congruent triangles, then there may exist a side of each of the small triangles that is included in, but does not coincide with, a side of the big triangle.

Comment: I'm not seeing how you create four congruent triangles like that.  So all you have to prove is non-emptiness, correct?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I now have an answer, which I am going to outline as follows. The most challenging part is showing that $\bigtriangleup(x^1,\ldots,x^k)\subseteq\bigcup_{E\in\mathscr E}E$ (in particular, $\mathscr E\neq\varnothing$), so I am going to focus on this.

In other words: I need to find for every point in $\bigtriangleup(x^1,\ldots,x^k)$ a face of some member of the subdivision $\mathscr T$ that has $k$ vertices and fully lies in $\bigtriangleup(x^1,\ldots,x^k)$.

> For example, if $k=3$, we want the triangle on the base $\bigtriangleup(x^1,x^2,x^3)$ to be intersected by a tetrahedron from the subdivision of the “big” tetrahedron $\bigtriangleup(x^1,x^2,x^3,x^4)$ not just at a single point, not just at a line segment, but actually a smaller triangle!

The case $k=1$ is rather trivial, so assume from now on that $k\geq 2$. In what follows, if $T\in\mathscr T$, then denote the vertices of the simplex $T$ by $y^1(T),\ldots,y^{k+1}(T)$, so that $$T=\bigtriangleup(y^1(T),\ldots,y^{k+1}(T)).$$

---

*Step 1$\quad$* Define, for each $\ell\in\{1,\ldots,k-1\}$, $$\mathcal I_{\ell}=\{I\,|\,I\subseteq\{1,\ldots,k+1\}\text{ and }\#I=\ell\}.$$ That is, $\mathcal I_{\ell}$ is simply the family of all the $\ell$-element subsets of the index set $\{1,\ldots,k+1\}$. For each $I\in\mathcal I_{\ell}$, define $$\mathscr T_{I}\equiv\{T\in\mathscr T\,|\,y^i(T)\in\bigtriangleup(x^1,\ldots,x^k)\text{ for each $i\in I$}\}.$$Furthermore, let $$W_T\equiv\bigtriangleup(\{y^i(T)\}_{i\in I})$$ for each $\ell\in\{1,\ldots,k-1\}$, $I\in\mathcal I_{\ell}$, and $T\in\mathscr T_I$. Finally, define $$W\equiv\bigcup_{\ell=1}^{k-1}\bigcup_{I\in\mathcal I_{\ell}}\bigcup_{T\in\mathscr T_I}W_T.$$ Intuitively, $W$ is the set of all points that can be expressed as a linear combination of at most $k-1$ vertices of some member of the subdivision $\mathscr T$. (Remark: I am pretty sure that the set $\mathscr T_I$ is never empty, but I didn’t bother checking that in detail because it is not really important for the purposes of the proof—you’ll see soon why not.)

---

*Step 2$\quad$* Fix, for a moment, $\ell\in\{1,\ldots,k-1\}$, $I\in\mathcal I_{\ell}$, and $T\in\mathscr T_I$. It is not difficult to check that $W_T\subseteq\bigtriangleup(x^1,\ldots,x^k)$ and that $W_T$ is closed in $\bigtriangleup(x^1,\ldots,x^k)$. The next step is to show that $W_T$ has empty interior in $\bigtriangleup(x^1,\ldots,x^k)$ (with respect to the relative Euclidean topology). Indeed, if one had for some $w\in W_T$ a small ball around $w$ contained in $W_T$, then one could define, for any $\varepsilon\in(0,1]$, $$a^i\equiv(1-\varepsilon)w+\varepsilon x^i$$ for each $i\in\{1,\ldots,k\}$. (Geometrically, think about “shrinking” the face $\bigtriangleup(x^1,\ldots,x^k)$ around $w$.) It is easily seen that the affine independence of $x^1,\ldots,x^k$ implies that of $a^1,\ldots,a^k$. But for small enough $\varepsilon$, $\{a^1,\ldots,a^k\}$ would be fully contained in $W_T$, which is a simplex with $\ell<k$ vertices—this would contradict affine independence. It follows that $W_T$ has empty (relative) interior and it is nowhere dense in $\bigtriangleup(x^1,\ldots,x^k)$.

---

*Step 3$\quad$* Since the union defining $W$ is finite, it follows that $W$ is also closed and nowhere dense in $\bigtriangleup(x^1,\ldots,x^k)$.

---

*Step 4$\quad$* Fix any $w\in\bigtriangleup(x^1,\ldots,x^k)$. The goal is to show that $w\in E$ for some $E\in\mathscr E$. Since $W$ is nowhere dense in $\bigtriangleup(x^1,\ldots,x^k)$, one can find for any $m\in\mathbb N$ some $w^{(m)}\in\bigtriangleup(x^1,\ldots,x^k)\setminus W$ such that $$\lVert w^{(m)}-w\rVert<\frac{1}{m},$$ where $\lVert\cdot\rVert$ is the $n$-dimensional Euclidean norm. Clearly, the sequence $(w^{(m)})_{m\in\mathbb N}$ converges to $w$. Since the union of the members of $\mathscr T$ yields $\bigtriangleup(x^1,\ldots,x^k,x^{k+1})$, there exists some $T^{(m)}\in\mathscr T$ such that $w^{(m)}\in T^{(m)}$, so that $$w^{(m)}=\sum_{i=1}^{k+1}\mu_i^{(m)}y^i(T^{(m)})$$ for some weight vector $(\mu_i^{(m)})_{i=1}^{k+1}$ whose elements are non-negative and sum up to $1$. Let $$I^{(m)}\equiv\{i\in\{1,\ldots,k+1\}\,|\,\mu_i^{(m)}>0\}.$$ Now, since $w^{(m)}$ takes zero weight from $x^{k+1}$ in the “big” simplex $\bigtriangleup(x^1,\ldots,x^k,x^{k+1})$, it follows that $y^i(T^{(m)})\in\bigtriangleup(x^1,\ldots,x^k)$ for every $i\in I^{(m)}$. This implies two things:

1. $\#I^{(m)}>k-1$, which follows from the fact that $w^{(m)}\notin W$; and
2. $\#I^{(m)}<k+1$, because not all of the affinely independent vertices $y^1(T^{(m)}),\ldots,y^{k+1}(T^{(m)})$ can lie in the proper face $\bigtriangleup(x^1,\ldots,x^k)$.

Thus, $\#I^{(m)}=k$. Showdown time: since $\mathscr T$ is finite, there exists a subsequence $(T^{(m_r)})_{r\in\mathbb N}$ whose terms are all the same; let me denote it by $T^0$. By the foregoing, $T^0$ has precisely $k$ vertices lying in $\bigtriangleup(x^1,\ldots,x^k)$; let the simplex spanned by these $k$ vertices be denoted as $E^0$. Clearly, $E^0\in\mathscr E$. Also, $E^0$ is closed in $\bigtriangleup(x^1,\ldots,x^k)$ and the subsequence $(w^{(m_r)})_{r\in\mathbb N}$ in $E^0$ converges to $w$. Therefore, $w\in E^0$, and the proof is complete. Any comments on it are greatly appreciated.